# tkinter frame display basics

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to create an application (well my very first) in Python/tkinter which ultimatively should run on a Raspberry Pi with a a small touchscreen display (480x320px) attached to it. The screen is divided into a mainframe and a frame which (later on) will contain 6 function keys (buttons)

So I started with below code, hoping/expecting that somehow I will get the main application window divided into two frames, one being grey, one being black ... but all I see (on my PC) is the MainApp window in correct size, not resizeable, with correct title (so far so good!) and a yellow background ... it seems the frames I defined inside MainApp are not displayed, even thoough there are Labels inside, they are sticky, they have a weight (and I can't remember what else I tried and where else I searched)

What am I overlooking here please?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk
#
# main application
#
class MainApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.title("My first GUI")
        self.parent.geometry("480x320")
        self.parent.resizable(width=False, height=False)
        self.parent.config(bg="yellow")

        mainframe = tk.Frame(self, bg="grey", width=480, height=280 )
        mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="WENS")
        tk.Label(mainframe, text="co-cooo").grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="WENS")

        fkeyframe = tk.Frame(self, bg="black", width=480, height=40)
        fkeyframe.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="WENS")
        tk.Label(fkeyframe, text="fo-fooo").grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="WENS")

        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=280)
        self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=40)
#
# define root element and start application
#
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MainApp(root)
    root.mainloop()  

#
# start if called from command line
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

#      0,0   MainApp (yellow)          480,0
#       +---------------------------------+
#       |   mainframe (grey, h=280)       |
#       |+-------------------------------+|
#       ||                               ||
#       ||                               ||
#       ||                               ||
#       |+-------------------------------+|
#       |   fkeyframe  (black, h=40)      |
#       |+-------------------------------+|
#       ||+----+----+----+----+----+----+||
#       ||| Bt | Bt | Bt | Bt | Bt | Bt |||
#       ||+----+----+----+----+----+----+||
#       |+-------------------------------+|
#       +---------------------------------+
#    320,0                             320,480
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `frame.grid_propagate(False)` in `__init__` to prevent resizing frame to dimensions of inner widgets:

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.parent.title("My first GUI")
    self.parent.geometry("480x320")
    self.parent.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    self.parent.config(bg="yellow")

    mainframe = tk.Frame(self, bg="grey", width=480, height=280 )
    mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="WENS")
    mainframe.grid_propagate(False)
    tk.Label(mainframe, text="co-cooo").grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="WENS")

    fkeyframe = tk.Frame(self, bg="black", width=480, height=40)
    fkeyframe.grid(column=0, row=1, sticky="WENS")
    mainframe.grid_propagate(False)
    tk.Label(fkeyframe, text="fo-fooo").grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="WENS")

    self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1, minsize=280)
    self.rowconfigure(1, weight=1, minsize=40)
```

Comment: partial improvement ... now I see grey and black with overlaying labels co-cooo & fo-fooo to the very left of the MainApp window, the rest (ca 80%) to the right still yellow ... so frames don't seem to respect the width I was requesting

Comment: Updated answer, look frame's `grid_propagate` method.

Comment: I started to reduce what I believe is redundant code, so `self.grid()` actually did some very good ... I am running into new phenomena now, so I accept your answer and open another when frust level raises above 10^6

Comment: `<frame>.grid_propagate(False)` killed some more phenomena ... thanks

Comment: Glad to help :-).

Comment: turning propagation off is the wrong solution. It is a decent enough workaround, but it requires that you calculate the exact sizes of all interior widgets in order to get the effect you want. Tkinter works best when you lay everything out logically and let it figure out the size of all interior widgets.

Comment: I have to disagree. This solution answers the question that was asked. Is there a better solution to do widgets placing? Probably yes, but question here was why the solution didn't worked, so this answer is correct. Your answer, on the other hand, is not, IMHO, because You used `pack` instead of `grid`, and I didn't saw that OP wanted to use that.

Comment: Fejs & Bryan you both added value to my question for which I am grateful ... I am currently absorbing both your inputs ... it's complex and/or I might be too old to start with Python ... let's see ;-)

Comment: Judging by the comments to your answer, you solved one problem but created others. That's exactly what happens with turning propagation off. It fixes an immediate problem but causes other problems. In my opinion, and in this specific case, turning propagation off fixed a _symptom_, not a _problem_.  As for my use of `pack`, that's a minor nit. I could have used `grid`, but that required three lines rather than one, with no added benefit.

Answer (score 2):

You are on the right track. I see you are being methodical, and only trying to solve one layout problem at a time, rather than trying to put all your widgets on the screen and then trying to fix them. That's definitely the best way to work when you are starting out.

The first problem is that you are neglecting to add `MainApp` to the main window. You create it, but you don't lay it out on the screen.

So, the very first step is to add it to the main window. Do this by calling `pack` or `place` or `grid` after creating it. Since it's the only widget inside the root window, `pack` is the simplest:

```
app.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

That will cause `MainApp` and all of its children to be visible.

The second problem is that you'll notice everything is now compacted and to the left side of the window. This is because you put `mainframe` inside of `MainApp` with `grid`, but you don't give any columns in `MainApp` a weight, so all of the extra space in the window as a whole goes unused. And, because frames want to shrink to fit their contents, your `mainframe` frame shrinks horizontally to fit the one widget that is inside it.

As a rule of thumb, if you place one or more widgets into a parent widget, you must always give a weight to at least one row *and* one column in the parent widget.

To do that, call `columnconfigure`, much like you call `grid_rowconfigure`:

```
self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

With that, your `mainframe` now covers the full upper portion of the window, and `fkeyframe` covers the bottom portion, and you can start adding more widgets.